# What's the ideal spot on Earth for a planned city?

Tags: geography

In my story, the megalomaniac wants to build a planned city, driven by a delusional utopian vision. Where should she site it?

Assume no political limits. Assume no budgetary limits. *This is only abut the geographical features of the site.*

Assume the misguided planners are dreaming of a paradise, not driven by economic imperatives. Obviously cities exist in sub-optimal places, but that's not what they want to build.

It should be in a region with ***low population density***. This is a tricky one. See my question is about  hidden gems, untapped desirable spots on planet earth. And maybe there are none because people tend to exploit resources and have had a few hundred years of free movement in which to do so, but it's worth a think. I'm sure next to Paris is a good spot for a city, but that's cheating because it's already taken. I'm not talking about totally empty, but in a county with under 60 people/km² would be best. For example, all of India is out. The dictator is looking for a greenfield site for a big city.

### Climate

I'm not sure exactly what climate is ideal for a city, willing to hear your thoughts. [Some academics have said that the ideal temperature for economic productivity is 13°C](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2015/oct/21/perfect-temperature-for-economic-success-is-13c-climate-change). I'm a little sceptical that research – partly because it is purely correlative. Paris has a mean temperature of 12.8° has done passably well at the ole city-development.

A more deductive, less inductive argument: the ideal temperature is one where you don't have bother about insulation and heating, makes life a lot easier. That would be about 20-21°, the temperature humans like best.

### Low seismic risk

Basically anywhere red on this map is out:

[image: seism]

### Low risk of tornadoes/hurricanes/damaging storms

[image: storm]

### Thought this dust map was pretty interesting too while we're doing maps. Dust is bad.

[image: dust]

Extreme dry seasons aren't good because they cause problems with dust. Some places (Lubumbashi, Serenje, Huambo) tick all the other boxes: moderate climates in most ways, no storms, no earthquakes, but they get dusty in the dry season. Dust is a bigger problem than people who haven't lived with it realise: bad for all kinds of machines including computers and the human machine.

### Excellent map of both earthquakes and storms. White means go.

[image: mapmap]

Comment: Cities are basically technology. Considering where cities over 1 million are located, it's only a question of getting required stuff in and out.

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more @BobaFit ? Do you mean transport routes are all-important?

Comment: How big a city? What purpose/s does it have?  (Governance, trade, manufacturing, tertiary education...?)  Where you say "no budget limit" - is that just the capital expenditure to build it or does it include operational expenditure to, for example, import potable water constantly?  If you have unlimited opex and capex and just want a city of universities and governing institutions then there's nothing to choose between any areas outside of the forbidden zones on your maps.  If you want a centre of trade and manufacture then we need to know what goods are involved.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 – let's try assuming unlimited capital spending with an eye to limiting ongoing spending. As for water resources, they need to be available locally, that's commonsense.

Comment: The main criterion for the location is of the city is what purpose the city is supposed to serve. Generally, cities are established and develop for a specific purpose; the purpose is most usually commercial in nature: a good port, a good place for a market, a stage along a commercial road, a good position for the manufacture of stuff, etc. When the city is established without any compelling reason for it to exist, it fails to thrive.

Comment: Yep @AlexP , as I alluded to at the start, the city will fail to thrive. The question is about its location

Comment: VTC:Too Story-Based. I was tempted to VTC when I read, "I'm not sure exactly what climate to look for here, willing to hear your thoughts." That nailed the coffin shut. Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum (see [tour]). Given unlimited wealth, the city can be anywhere on the planet, which makes this an invitation to help your character make a decision, which is off-topic. Per the [help/on-topic], "If ... you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site." You need to provide a complete and well-defined list of conditions.

Comment: The current location of Los Angeles is good, except for the low population density part. Nothing a genocide can't solve though. If you don't like it's seismology, I suggest any number of other current city locations. After all, we're not assuming any political limitations here.

Comment: Los Angeles scores about 1/5 , people would abandon it if they had any sense. Why live in a desert climes prone to earthquakes, mosquitoes, drought, overheating, with 35 days of rain a year, and a 30% chance of a >9.0 earthquake in the next 50 years?

Comment: I volunteer West Alton, Mo. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Alton,_Missouri Not a lot of people to clear out. The primary issue with the location is that it's subject to periodic flooding, but a reasonable investment in infrastructure could fix that.

Comment: Look into the city of Almere, Netherlands. It is a thriving city fully built on reclaimed land. With an unlimited budget and a good bit of Dutch engeneering, you could easily extend any existing coastline and pop a city down right where you like it best.

Comment: @Wokopa Why should the character  care about the weather or climate for their city?  Are they stupid enough to build a city with a lot of separate unconnected buildings insteead of one giant building?

Comment: @M.A.Golding I would say you're thinking outside the box, only the opposite seems to fit too....

Comment: Why not just overlap those images and isolate your potential candidates? Then you can do some additional research on those areas, and see what fits your narrative best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Amapá, Brazil

The north of Brazil strikes a nice balance between all your requirements. It is just to the south of the Atlantic hurricane zone, and far from the seismically active north and west faults along the South American Plate. At the same time, it is the most sparsely populated of the Brazilian coastal states, with just 5 people per square km. As a bonus, it has a low chance for dust and a warm climate year-round (high of ~32C and low of ~24C).

Amapa's coast on the central Atlantic makes it a great place for a city with unlimited money to spend on new infrastructure. Currently it is neglected by the Brazilian state, but you can drop a sack of cash to set up docking facilities and easily ship in materials for further construction (and ship out any trade products).

Comment: This is an excellent answer. All clear on the last map I posted (https://i.imgur.com/MLRI2qR.png), even for the little things like hailstorms, year round rainfall, population density of 4.7/km² across the region. It's about 6°C warmer than it should be, but otherwise perfect.

Comment: Really that whole stretch of coast from Guyana or Suriname eastwards through to Amapá is really nice. West Guyana and you're starting to get into hurricane territory.

Comment: I am a brazilian and I already went there. Macapá (Amapá's capital) is a paradise known by few outsiders. The interior of the state is also a very beautiful place. However, it might be too hot for what the OP intends.

Comment: Fun fact: It lies over the equator. So much that the Macapá's soccer stadium was built to have the midfield line exactly over the equator down to millimetric precision. The stadium is at the end of the Equatorial Avenue which was also built right over the equator.

Comment: Feeding on to my last comment – plus I don't want to use the idea of going to Guyana to create a misguided Utopia, as that has certain..... uhhh... associations

Comment: There are a few sites in Amapa that have low risk of natural disasters: https://revistapesquisa.fapesp.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/disasters03_249.jpg However, the entire area is a tropical monsoon climate, so you can expect heavy rains from December until July. https://weather-and-climate.com/average-monthly-Rainfall-Temperature-Sunshine-region-amapa-br,Brazil . This makes the area prone to mudslides and avalanches.

Answer (score 3):

## 20.8°E over the equator

This is in the north of the Democratic Republic of Congo.

- No hurricanes or tornados.
- Very low on dust rate (I specifically looked for that small pale green blob over the north of the DRC in the map).
- No seismic hazard.
- Currently in an isolated place in the middle of a dense tropical forest.
- The nearest cities are [Mbandaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbandaka), some 282 km west of this place and [Boende](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boende), 32 km to the south-southeast. Mbandaka is a big city, while Boende is a small town. There are other small hamlets and farms closer, but they are just that: small hamlets and farms. They are along the unpaved M8 road that passes roughly 6.6 km from there to the northwest.
- About the climate, it should be very similar to Mbandaka and Boende climates. Mbandaka's year's average low is 19 °C and average high is 31 °C. Boende's years's average low is 20.4 °C and average high is 30.4 °C. Both places have very little (< 2 °C) variation from the coldest to the hottest month. I.e. this place has a temperature that is seldom outside the 18 to 32 °C range and it varies very little in the year.
- Also, it features moderate rainfall. Not too much but nor too little.

Comment: Good answer, thank you

Comment: A slight improvement might be to go 200km north just to get the Congo River (the 2nd biggest river in the world by output). So on the Congo river somewhere between Lisala and Mbandaka: https://osm.org/go/wKPBnF-

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've found –

**Corsica** – No hurricanes, tornadoes, or earthquakes, excellent location (especially for an air base), and [Bonifacio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonifacio,_Corse-du-Sud#Climate) averages 10.5° in its coldest month, 24.8° in its hottest. The population density of Corsica is 40/km²

**North coast of Tasmania** – Population density of Tasmania is 8.3/km², but 40% them are in Hobart in the south. As a negative, there is a proneness to earthquakes, but only VI on the [Modified Mercalli intensity scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Mercalli_intensity_scale), which may not be a dealbreaker. The [climate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devonport,_Tasmania#Climate) is colder than Corsica, but never extreme.

**Coast of Suriname** – If you like it tropical. Southeast of the hurricane belt. [Coronie district](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronie_District) is coastal but has less than 1 person per km², the [climate](https://weatherspark.com/y/29323/Average-Weather-in-Totness-Suriname-Year-Round#Sections-Temperature) averages 26°, which is a few degrees warmer than it should be but not much, and because it's equatorial there's little seasonal variation, and there's no dry season. Drawback: mosquitoes.

**Ireland, possibly Kilkenny** – Ireland is [unique](https://64.media.tumblr.com/02b1616847aa8d7a02cf30cdbf16f710/326ad7997d9af046-ef/s1280x1920/821de3ce9eb65031c0a8fc530bbc7bf68616002e.jpg) in being depopulated over the past 180 years. There's probably some historical reason, but it means what is still a UK-like climate, known to support advanced civilisation, is empty. I pick Kilkenny because it's close to Europe while still being empty. It's about the least seismically-active place in the whole world.

**Southern coast of Buenos Aires Province** – "Hey that's cheating you said next to existing major cities was cheating you cheater". No, Buenos Aires city is 450-500km from the southern coast, outside the province. The coast is largely unpeopled, is too far south for mosquitoes and has no earthquakes or storms. The [climate of Mar Del Plata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar_del_Plata#Climate) has a mean of 7.5° in the coldest month and 20.4° (aka 'room temperature') in the warmest, and has the rain spread through the year. *(PS: I overlooked that this place has a lot of tornadoes)*

Thanks for all the replies so far.

Answer (score 0):

I volunteer [West Alton, Mo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Alton,_Missouri).

Pluses:

- Not a lot of people to clear out.
- Good access to water, transportation, and communication
- Highly defensible position between two rivers

Minuses:

- Currently permanently a flood plain. Lack of residents makes this something that it would take an evil genius to solve.
- Occasional tornadoes
- Can get earthquakes up to 5.3 or so
- Not remote

Comment: Re: getting flooded. At least in some cases there is a solution. It's not easy exactly, but it's not complicated.  https://www.environmentandsociety.org/tools/keywords/duffs-ditch-red-river-floodway-winnipeg

Comment: Oh, it's far worse than that. In the late 80's, they had a flood where, literally, the entire city was six feet under water for a couple of weeks. He did, however, say infinite money for setup.

Comment: The problem with West Alton is the climate.  The question asks for "no need for insulation or heating", while West Alton swings from an average high of 31 C to an average low of -8 C, requiring insulation, heating, and air conditioning.  In general, the only locations meeting the climate criteria will be near-equatorial locations on the sea coast.

Comment: @Mark, no doubt there. Even the zoo is indoors in St. Louis.

Comment: The question was a place with good climate and no disasters.

Comment: @wokopa, I'm pretty sure that no place exists that has all of the qualities presented. Costal areas are subject to tsunamis and hurricanes. Mountainous areas have earthquakes, and flat areas have tornados. You might look to sub-saharan Africa, in places like southern Chad, but then you have to deal with swarms of warlords and lack of infrastructure. I'd be happy to see West Alton pushed to the bottom of the heap, but let's call it "someone can do better."

Comment: @RobertRapplean that is all incorrect. [Hurricanes and earthquakes](https://i.imgur.com/MLRI2qR.png) are extremely localised. Coastal = hurricane is completely wrong. [Coastal = tsunami-prone is equally wrong](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-m_qJU-XEwss/UcHKXwUONcI/AAAAAAAABa8/bgkfxgh0Ai0/s1600/Tsunami_zonas_peligrosas.jpg). What are you basing these claims on? [Flat = tornado-prone is also wrong](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/0d/2c/d7/0d2cd7827d91d8defdf8cf0905abb5ad--tornado-world-maps.jpg).

Comment: @wokopa, all generalizations are wrong. This is only the US, but try to find anywhere in our country that isn't red for some form of disaster. Yea, I live in the US, so my information base is biased in that direction. https://www.envistaforensics.com/knowledge-center/insights/articles/envista-natural-disaster-risk-areas-infographic-and-interactive-map/

Comment: You'll notice that the entire east coast is marked as hurricane-prone, and the entire west coast is tsunami-prone. The tornado-prone area is the entire central great-plains breadbasket. I request that you identify where you heard that earthquakes were localized. Without exception, the entire Pacific rim is earthquake prone. https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/17s0fhjkuo9ewjpg.jpg

Comment: Hurricanes are a problem on all eastern coasts in the northern hemisphere between about 5 degrees north and 45 degrees north. Further north is too cold for anything you want. Southern hemisphere is less prone to such, so that's a clear exception. https://www.flickr.com/photos/idvsolutions/7840356344/sizes/h/in/photostream/

Comment: @RobertRapplean, "mountain = earthquake" is also wrong: West Alton is solidly within the danger area of the [New Madrid Seismic Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Madrid_Seismic_Zone).

Comment: @Mark, https://www.pinterest.com/pin/288089707387714620/ It's really tectonic plate edges, but mountains are one of the common side-effects. Besides, I didn't say that earthquakes only happen in mountains, I said that mountains are generally earthquake prone. I can't help but feel like you're reaching.

Comment: Thanks for this list of places that are not the answer @RobertRapplean